# Add to Array of wildcards in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and looking to test something for a POC.
There are multiple files stored on the cloud inbox (File_1.txt, File_2.txt and so on).

I want to add these files using a wildcard to an array and then run some commands (specific to the cloud) for each file.

I cannot specify the -Path in the code as the files are located on cloud and I do not have the path.

The below code works:

```
 $files = @("File_1.txt","File_2.txt","File_3.txt")
 foreach ($file in $files) {
   Run commands on cloud like...delete inbox/$file
 }
```

However I cannot hard code the file names. I am looking to add file names using wildcard.

```
  $files=@("File*.txt")
   foreach ($file in $files) {
     Run commands on cloud like...inbox/$file
   }
```

But this does not work as in the log it is taking File*.txt as the name of the file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can easily update the file number using *string interpolation*.  Here is a basic example of how this might work:

```
1 .. 10 | 
    ForEach-Object {
        "hello" | Out-File -Path "File_$_.txt"
    }
```

Here we generate an array of the numbers from 1 to 10 (using the range operator `..`), then this is piped to our command (and hence placed in the `$_` variable).  As each number comes through, the path is constructed with the current value of `$_`, so you get `File_1.txt`, `File_2.txt`, etc.

You can use other looping techniques, but the key is that you can build the filename/path on-the-fly by having PowerShell replace the variables for you.

Comment: Thanks ...this works but I the number of files could vary..how do I address that ?

Comment: @SQL_Rookie, how would you know the names/number of files normally?  You said they are stored in the cloud and not accessible to query directly or you could use `Get-ChildItem` to find them.

Comment: The product which is on cloud exports the data file...It could vary depending on the size of data. I think Get-ChildItem is what should work but unfortunately I cannot get the path to the inbox directory on cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dir` equivalent of PowerShell, `Get-ChildItem` (In fact `dir` and `ls` are aliases for the Cmdlet) to search files using wildcards:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem file*.txt
foreach($file in $files) {
    DoSomeStuffWithFile $file
}
```

`Get-ChildItem` returns `FileInfo` objects. If you want to use the filename `String` in the loop, you should refer to the `Name` property of the object:

```
DoSomeStuffWithFileName $file.Name
```